# A faster way than typing multiple else if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, console

I'm doing a random name generator for enemies in my console game, I have it pick a random number, and based on the number it gives the enemy a name. I want a cleaner look with my code and also for future reference don't want to type out 10+ else if statements. Is there an easier way to do this, or am I just going to have to continue doing it like this?

```
void chooseName()
{
    Random numGen = new Random();
    int number = numGen.Next(0, 10);
    
    if (number == 1)
    { }
 
    else if (number == 2)
    { }

    else if (number == 3)
    { }

    else if (number == 4)
    { }

    else if (number == 5)
    { }

    else if (number == 6)
    { }

    else if (number == 7)
    { }

    else if (number == 8)
    { }

    else if (number == 9)
    { }

    else
    { }
}
```

Comment: An array of 10 names? Then index into the array?

Comment: If you need different data (a name) based on the number, then an array as suggested by @canton7 is perfect.  If you need different logic, then read about `switch` / `case`.

Comment: Take a look at [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression)

Comment: If you want to go Object oriented. you would create a IEnemies interface and create enemy objects in your swithc. After this you can use the interface for generic actions and implement their actions in the real objects. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7qwuFnyIpM

Comment: To avoid multiple if/else statement you can replace them with Dictionary (in your case - Dictionary<int, string> { [1] = "Name1", [2] = "Name2" ...  }). Define this dictionary as private static in your class. Then you can extract control logic in separate method that will do simple thing - dic.TryGetValue(number, out string enemyName) ? enemyName : throw new NotImplementedException("Number not implemented").

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well. You have 10 names and you want to draw 1 name randomly? If that is the case:

Make list of Enemy names. Generate random number from 0 to the `enemyList.Length - 1`

Take the element from the list based on a random number generated.

```
var enemyName = enemyList[randomNumber]
```

In future you just add new name in a list of Enemies and code will work...